# std::fstream files more than 2gb

Tags: c++, fstream

What strategy should I use if I have an implementation of std::fstream with 32-bit std::streampos? If I want to move position I can do it in several steps(10gb - 10 times +1gb). How can I get position? Or should I keep current position in some variable outside fstream?

P.S. I can't change the implementation of STL.

Comment: What do you mean by "10gb - 10 times +1gb"?@Andreo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of the current position yourself is the most straight-forward answer, if you're unable to addle the STL.  If your compiler support the `long long` type, I'd go with that.